getting server IP address from VueJS 2 application
I have a VueJS application running on Ubuntu linux, I know that in Vue it does a lot of the rendering client side.
Is there a way of getting the server ip address from a Vue JS application as all the calls I run report back the client IP address.
fetch ('http://ipinfo.io/json')
         .then (response => response.json()) 
         .then (response => {
          console.log ("info: ", response);})
         .catch ( error => { console.log ("error: ", error); });

Any ideas? Thank you in advance
Looked on Stackover and searched goooogle.

Do a fetch req  for any file, in the response headers there should also be the address of the contacted server

Thank you very much.
